# regarding multiple files upload in single form

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on my project I want to upload images with single form but I have two input fields. I want when I choose the both images on both input fields when I submit it I want my both files are stored in the folder I show you my code but with this code, I am getting only one image. I want both images which I am uploaded. my form looks like this

[image]

```
Here is my code:

public function upload_creative_workshop_image($post, $files){
    //print_r($files); die;
    $allowedExts= array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
    $temp = explode(".", $files["image1"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($files["image1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") //check image is mp3
    || ($files["image1"]["type"] == "image/gif") //check image is mp4
    || ($files["image1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")  //check image is jpg
    || ($files["image1"]["type"] == "image/png")) //check image is png
    && ($files["image1"]["size"]) //check if image size is below 6MB
    && in_array(trim($extension), $allowedExts)) //check the extensions also
        {
            if($files["image1"]["error"] > 0){
                echo $files["image1"]["error"];
            }
            else{
        $filename = $files["image1"]["name"];
        $upload= move_uploaded_file($files["image1"]["tmp_name"], $this->img_path.$filename);
        //print_r($upload); die;
        if($upload){
            //$this->store_image_indb($filename, $post);
                }
            }
        }else{

            echo "<h1>please upload image only</h1>";
        }
}
```

Comment: You have to call your function for each image you want to upload. In this case, your inputfields should have different names like `image1` and `image2`. **BUT** what I would do is to make your input field multiple and then call your function once with the images in `$files` array. For that you have to add a loop into your function.

Comment: yeah I have both fields are the different name like this:

Comment: <td><input type="file" name="image1" value="<?php echo $image1;?>"></td>

Comment: <input type="file" name="image2" value="<?php echo $image2;?>">

Comment: what do you see, when you call `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different names like 'image1' and 'image2' then please check below solution:

You have to run loop of $_FILES array like below and have to modify your upload function slightly as below.

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES)) {
    if (COUNT($_FILES) >= 1) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $i_key => $image_file) {
        $testObject = new test();
        $testObject->upload_creative_workshop_image($image_file);
}
}
}

class test {
 function upload_creative_workshop_image($image){
    //print_r($files); die;
    $allowedExts= array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
    $temp = explode(".", $image["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($image["type"] == "image/jpeg") //check image is mp3
    || ($image["type"] == "image/gif") //check image is mp4
    || ($image["type"] == "image/jpg")  //check image is jpg
    || ($image["type"] == "image/png")) //check image is png
    && ($image["size"]) //check if image size is below 6MB
    && in_array(trim($extension), $allowedExts)) //check the extensions also
    {
        if($image["error"] > 0){
            echo $image["error"];
        }
        else{
    $filename = $image["name"];
    $upload= move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], 'uploads/'.$filename);
    //print_r($upload); die;
    if($upload){
        //$this->store_image_indb($filename, $post);
            }
        }
    }else{

        echo "<h1>please upload image only</h1>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not right code with this code m facing many errors  and your code have many errors some variables are not matched  with  loop and functions

Comment: This is perfectly running code I tried it my self. If u know oops then you can run it without error.

Comment: yeah i am using in this project but when i use this code i am facing error can u tell me this php code where should i place it means which file  m not talking about function m talking about top code which u tell me

Comment: You should add that $_FILES loop when u Submit form and inside this loop only u should call function.

Comment: can u send me ur skype id and linked in id i can share my files with you and properly discuss and m also girl u can if u want please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can use multitype form data like

```
<form method=post action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type=file name='images[]'>
```

Comment: i also use this

Comment: <form name="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">

Comment: @kulu can you provide me with the JS code side? on return validate()